# Check if map is Content/Measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $\mu(A) := 
\begin{cases}
1; \text{if $A$ contains at least one natural number}\\
0; \text{else}
\end{cases}$ be a map for $A \in \mathcal{B}^1$, where $\mathcal{B}^1$ is the [Borel-Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) (sigma-algebra) over $\mathbb{R}$. Check if $\mu$ is a [Content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_(measure_theory)). If so; check if $\mu$ is [Sigma-Additive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_additivity).

To check if it's a Content, we simply have to verify that $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$, which is true since the empty-set does not contain any natural numbers; and that $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ for $A \cap B = \emptyset$ with $A, B \in \mathcal{B}^1$.

My question is regarding the last sentence. Let's take $(0; 1], (1; 2] \in \mathcal{B}^1$. Then $\mu((0; 1] \cup (1; 2]) = \mu((0; 2]) = 1$, since $1 \in (0; 2]$. Also $\mu((0; 1]) + \mu((1; 2]) = 1 + 1 = 2$, since $1 \in (0; 1]$ and $2 \in (1; 2]$. Therefore $\mu(A \cup B) \neq \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ for these two sets.

What bothers me is that the second part of this exercise (i.e. show sigma-additivity) becomes useless if $\mu$ turns out to be not even additive. Where is my mistake?

EDIT: i made a terrible mistake! the task was not to check if $\mu$ is sigma-additive, but sigma-**sub**additive! $\mu$ does indeed not define a content (at least by the above counter-example..), but satisfies the condition to be sigma-**sub**additive! will try to prove the later now and update this question afterwards..